# How to know if I have/need Linux server or Windows server?

Tags: mysql, php, sql, html

I am creating a classifieds website with PHP and MYSQL.

How would I know if I need windows server or Linux?

I am about to pick a host.

Any other suggestions are also appreciated...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention what you have experience with, which would be a big factor. But basically, unless you have a particular reason for Windows (for instance, it's familiar whereas you've never used Linux, that sort of thing), I'd go with a Linux server since hosting companies usually have to charge you more for Windows machines (because of the license). Seems to me last I looked for a new host, Windows added between $10 and $20 / month to a dedicated server package. (You haven't said you're looking for dedicated, I'm just saying.)

Answer (score 8):

I hate to be blunt, but if you need to ask, then you probably aren't the person who should be deciding.

Comment: +1 - just what I was thinking

Answer (score 4):

I hate to be vague but, either will work. Choose whichever OS that you are most comfortable with.

Comment: +1, this is the most important point.

Answer (score 0):

I would say (no trolling), use a linux/unix system for this as you don't need ASP. You'll certainly learn a lot more this way.

Comment: I don't think one should be using a live environment with real life users accessing it as a learning platform.

Comment: Nevertheless i think he's going to learn something new anyway as he don't really know what platform to choose. As you said: the day you stop learning is the day you may as well give up.